# Java: implementations of method for different class instances

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, inheritance, abstract-class

Project on Java with Spring Boot.

I have one generic service

```
@Service
public class GenericService
```

And several classes that inherit GenericService:

```
@Service
public class Entity1Service extends GenericService

@Service
public class Entity2Service extends GenericService
```

Entity classes:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ENTITY_SEQ")
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ProcessState processState;
}

@Entity
public class Entity1 extends AbstractEntity {
     // some specific fields
}

@Entity
public class Entity2 extends AbstractEntity {
     // some specific fields
}
```

I have to write similar methods in both of child classes and one generic in base class:

```
@Service
public class Entity1Service extends GenericService {
     public void startEntity1Process(AbstractEntity entity) {
       Entity1 entity1 = (Entity1) entity; 
       // perform some specific operations 
    }
}

@Service
public class Entity2Service extends GenericService {
     public void startEntity2Process(AbstractEntity entity) { 
        Entity2 entity2 = (Entity2) entity; 
       // perform some specific operations 
    }
}
```

I writing a generic method in base class:

```
@Service
public class GenericService {

@Autowired
Entity1Service entity1Service;

@Autowired
Entity1Service entity2Service;

     public void startEntityProcess(AbstractEntity entity) { 
        if (entity instance of Entity1)
            entity1Service.startEntity1Process(entity);
        else if (entity instance of Entity2)
            entity2Service.startEntity2Process(entity);
    }
}
```

I received the error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.process.Entity1Service] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

I suggest, that the cause of the error is that I'm trying to autowire bean of subclass in parent class.

**1. How can I avoid this error in current implementation?**

**2. Is there a better solution for solving this kind of task?**

Maybe I've to try declare `public void startEntityProcess(AbstractEntity entity)` as abstract and then ovverride it? But how I will distinguish instance of entities then?

Comment: Can you show your Configuration with component scan. Are your sure the Entity1Service is being scanned?

Comment: Yes, it's working separately. This error occured only after autowiring it in parent class. This service autowired in several other classes and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved by using @Autowired and constructor.

Change GenericService to

```
@Service
public class GenericService {

    Entity1Service entity1Service;

    Entity2Service entity2Service;

    @Autowired
    public GenericService(Entity1Service entity1Service, Entity2Service entity2Service){
        this.entity1Service=entity1Service;
        this.entity2Service=entity2Service;
    }

    public GenericService(){

    }

     public void startEntityProcess(AbstractEntity entity) { 
        if (entity instance of Entity1)
            entity1Service.startEntity1Process(entity);
        else if (entity instance of Entity2)
            entity2Service.startEntity2Process(entity);
    }
}
```

---

or just use @Autowired(required=false)

```
@Service
public class GenericService {
    @Autowired(required=false)
    Entity1Service entity1Service;

    @Autowired(required=false)
    Entity2Service entity2Service;

     public void startEntityProcess(AbstractEntity entity) { 
        if (entity instance of Entity1)
            entity1Service.startEntity1Process(entity);
        else if (entity instance of Entity2)
            entity2Service.startEntity2Process(entity);
    }
}
```

I tested it. It would work using either one of both.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a different approach.

Change this

```
@Service
public class GenericService
```

to

```
public interface GenericService {
  void startEntityProcess(AbstractEntity entity);
}
```

and make two implementations

```
@Service
public class Entity1Service implements GenericService {
     public void startEntityProcess(AbstractEntity entity) {
       Entity1 entity1 = (Entity1) entity; 
       // perform some specific operations 
    }
}

@Service
public class Entity2Service implements GenericService {
     public void startEntityProcess(AbstractEntity entity) { 
        Entity2 entity2 = (Entity2) entity; 
       // perform some specific operations 
    }
}
```

And then inject Entity1Service or Entity2Service as needed

---

Or another option is to just have

```
public interface EntityService {
  void startEntityProcess(AbstractEntity entity);
}
```

and

```
@Service
public class EntityServiceImpl implements EntityService {
     public void startEntityProcess(AbstractEntity entity) { 
 // if instance of Entity 1 call startEntity1Process
 // if instance of Entity 2 call startEntity2Process
    }

public void startEntity1Process(Entity1 entity) {}
public void startEntity2Process(Entity2 entity) {}
}
```